# Position of Tracked Individuals

Tags: openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using NiUserTracker or openni_tracker.cpp, what measurement is used for the values of the x, y, and z variables? Centimeters? Inches?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10859/position-of-tracked-individuals/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it's correctly done, it should be meters: [Standard Units](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-11**:
In case other people need to know, I found that NiUserTracker uses millimeters.